# to find the blocks of "1" in the given matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There is a two-dimensional matrix, elements only 0 and 1; element 1 of the upper and lower left and right elements of 1, can be defined as neighbors; as many neighbors as a group, ask how many groups of the matrix?

[image: example]

If you have idea about this question, I would like to your answer with java language.

Comment: Look up *depth-first search*.

Comment: I see only 3 blocks in the example, considering upper and lower left are neighbors. Also, nobody here will give you an answer to your homework. 
Take a look at connected component algorithms, bfs, and dfs
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Comment: @Logar I believe OP means areas which are connected only by one vertical or horizontal movement; i.e. the 1 near the bottom right is in its own group.

Comment: yup that would make sense. Thanks - Oops, misread your comment. If there is also vertical movements, the upper and lower left are one group, +2 separate groups in the bottom right. What am I missing ?

Comment: @Logar by that I mean from any element inside the group you can reach an adjacent element with only one *either* vertical *or* horizontal movement

Comment: @meowgoesthedog So, {0, 0} and {0, 5} are connected right ? Meh, I give it up, can't see the 4th group

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a variant of standard 'Counting no.of Connected Components' in undirected graph. You can find clear explanation and implementation of this problem as finding no of islands - [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-islands/).